# how to format output file in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to format my output file exactly like my input file. I was wondering if anyone could give me some pointers. My codes are:

```
input_file=open('abcd.txt','r')

f1=input('file name: ')

output_file=open(f1,'w')
for line in input_file:
    output_file.write(line)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

My input file looks like the following. Where country is 50 chars long, second category is 6 chars, third is 3 chars, fourt is 25 chars, and year is 4 chars long. The following is the inputfile.

```
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   68 Eastern Mediterranean     2012
Albania                                            WB_LMI  90 Europe                      1980
Albania                                            WB_LMI  90 Europe                    1981
```

The following is how my output file looks like:

```
Afghanistan                                        WB_LI   68 Eastern Mediterranean     2012
Albania                                           WB_LMI  90 Europe                    1980
Albania                                           WB_LMI  90 Europe                    1981
```

Comment: You are writing each line from `input_file` to `f1` exactly as read. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was copying and pasting from a bigger file and forgot to change the variable.

Comment: If you're getting all your output in one line, maybe you should try adding a line break ("\n") after each line you print.

Comment: What exactly is your problem, it looks like input and output are identical and that is what you want, isn't it? Please provide more details on the issue

Comment: For some reason, when I am pasting my output file and input file in here, they are looking identical. But, on my computer screen, they are not looking like they are identically aligned.

Comment: Ok, now, the output file looks exactly how it should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings), mainly `{:-x}` where `x` denotes the minimal length of the string (filled with whitespace) and `-` denotes to left-align the contents:

```
output_file.write('{:-50} {:-6} {:-3} {:-25} {:-4}\n'.format(country, category, third, fourth, year))
```